# Java read and encode large binary file

Tags: java, file, jsp, binary, base64

Faced with the problem to read and encode any file with size up to 100 MB. I've code that works just fine on small txt files and code, that can deal with large amounts of data. The problem is that the last one not working for unknown reason. 
Tried to google around with no luck and thats why I'm here.

```
//Working snippet. Readind putty does nothing.
final String fileName = "C:\\putty.exe";
InputStream inStream = null;
BufferedInputStream bis = null;

try {
    inStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    bis = new BufferedInputStream(inStream);

    int numByte = bis.available();
    byte[] buf = new byte[numByte];

    bis.read(buf, 0, numByte);
    buf = Base64.encodeBase64(buf);
    for (byte b : buf) {
        out.write(b);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally { 
    if (inStream != null)
        inStream.close();
    if (bis != null)
        bis.close();
}
```

The following snippet was derived from the other responses here.

```
BufferedReader br = null;
long fsize;
int bcap;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

FileChannel fc = new FileInputStream(fileName).getChannel();
fsize = fc.size();
ByteBuffer bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fsize);
bb.flip();
bcap = bb.capacity();
while (bb.hasRemaining() == true) {
    bcap = bb.remaining();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[bcap];
    bb.get(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    String str = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(bytes));            
    sb.append(str);
}
fc.close();
((DirectBuffer) bb).cleaner().clean();

String resultString = sb.toString();
out.write(resultString);
out.write("test");
```

Here is the exception I got

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /read.jsp at line 57
54:         while (bb.hasRemaining() == true)
55:             bcap = bb.remaining();
56:             byte[] bytes = new byte[bcap];
57:             bb.get(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
58:             String str = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(bytes));            
59:             sb.append(str);
60:         fc.close();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are always making the buffer the same size as the file. **Don't**. For large files you will have to stream the data with a smallish buffer (maybe 8K, but test to optimise) and using a [CharsetEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html).

Comment: @BoristheSpider ok, got it. First code is a proof-of-concept, thats why so ugly. Expected some hints how to make second one work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't keep using base64 on little chunks you will have no idea how to decode it later, Since all the base64 strings combined will create one large base64 string which you will have no way to figure out where each chunk of the base64 string starts or ends. Plus you can't predict the size of the base64 string

You must create the base64 string on the whole file bytes at once no other way around this.

Try replacing

```
bb.get(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
```

with

```
bb.get(bytes, 0, bcap);
```

or

```
bb.get(bytes, 0, bb.remaining());
```

or maybe

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[bcap+1];
```

I can't comment I don't have 50 reputation.

Comment: Tried all suggestions with no luck. First ugly and slow solution works and encoded bytes was decoded correctly.